# Beginner with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, command

I am fairly new with python, as I am learning on my own I encounter some minimal errors a students would mostly ask their professors but I dont have the luxury to do that right now so I am here. 
I want to check if Tkinter is installed using command on my Pc BUT I get a syntax error message, can someone help me with that? 
I typed -> `python -m tkinter`

```
--------------------------------
>> python -m tkinter
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python -m tkinter
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: We (at least not I) are not professors. SO does not aim to tutor languages - you should look for tutorials: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: thats because you are trying to run the command as a python code, just type the command in the console without starting python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a quick one-liner, you can run the following from any command line:

`python -c "import tkinter"`

It will either output an error if it doesn't exist, or nothing if the module exists. For example, I can see this:

```
$ python -c "import tkinter"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tkinter
$ python -c "import array"
$
```

Answer (score 0):

That command is for shell enviroment.

Inside python interpreter you can check it by

```
import tkinter
```